# protractor : Best way to use in protractor ? driver.get("URL") or browser.get("URL")

Tags: protractor

Which is best way to use in protractor ?

```
var driver = browser.driver;
driver.get("URL")
```

or

```
browser.get("URL")
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(browser.params.implicitWaitTime);
```

Currently I have used second approach to open URL and perform any browser action. Should I change everything like first approach or my approach is nice to go ahead ?

Answer (score 2):

My two cents

1. If its a non angular application - go For `browser.driver.get()`
   If not go for `browser.get('')`
   browser.get understands the angular cycle and waits for the angular activity to finish

from documentation - [API Documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.get)

> Navigate to the given destination and loads mock modules before
>   Angular. Assumes that the page being loaded uses Angular. If you need
>   to access a page which does not have Angular on load, use the wrapped
>   webdriver directly.

2. If you are using `browser.get()` then you dont need a implicit wait and ideally you should avoid using it

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will implement this and will update this. If everything works great, will mark this as answer.